# Approximation of combination $ {n \choose k} = \Theta \left( n^k \right) $?

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics, computational-complexity, combinations

Is it a valid to say 
$$
{n \choose k} = \Theta \left( n^k \right)
$$
for any $n$ and $k$? If so, how to prove it?

Note: $k$ is not a function of $n$.

Note: Observed it here (page 5): 
 http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~sinclair/cs271/n6.pdf

[image]

Comment: Only as long as $k$ is a constant which does not depend on $n$ -- otherwise, it could be false.

Comment: Thanks. Let's assume that it is fixed. I added to the question. Could you give hints on the proof?

Comment: It is quite easy to show that for fixed $k$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{n^k}=\frac{1}{k!}$.

Comment: At first I was wondering what the capital omega function was, and then I facepalmed when I realized from the answers that it was "Big Oh" notation from CS.  Then I double facepalmed as if coming across Homer's Odyssey in Ελληνική and then discovering "oh, this is a Greek translation of the original English poem."

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have that 
$$
\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!} = \frac{1}{k!}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}
= \frac{1}{k!}\left(n(n-1)(n-2)\dots(n-k+1)\right).
$$
As far as the $\Theta(\cdot)$ notation is concerned, $k$ is a constant, so $\frac{1}{k!}=\Theta(1)$, and 
$$
\left(n(n-1)(n-2)\dots(n-k+1)\right) = n^k\cdot\left(1\left(1-\frac1n\right)\left(1-\frac2n\right)\dots\left(1-\frac kn\right)\right)
$$
and as $k$ is fixed,,
$$
\left(1\left(1-\frac1n\right)\left(1-\frac2n\right)\dots\left(1-\frac kn\right)\right) \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 1
$$
so that indeed $$
\binom{n}{k} = \Theta(n^k)
$$

Comment: But is $n \choose n/2$ $ \sim n^{n/2} \sim \exp(n/2 \log n)$ polynomial?

Comment: @PeterLeopold The approximation only holds for *constant* $k$, and breaks for $k=k(n)$ (as in your example). For instance, $\binom{n}{n/2} = \Theta(2^{n/2}/\sqrt{n})$. (There are various proofs of this, some using Sitrling's approximation, some others using a probabilistic interpretation.)

Comment: Your logic is partially correct, and you're on the right track, but there's a small error in your reasoning. Please take a look at my answer below.

Comment: The question is about the value of the binomial coefficient, not the time complexity to compute it. Your answer is not answering the question.

Answer (score 4):

We can even make a stronger statement that $${n \choose k} = O\left (\left( \frac{e \cdot n}{k} \right)^k \right)$$ For the proof, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1352338/proof-for-the-upper-bound-and-lower-bound-for-binomial-coefficients).

Comment: I would mention that this is especially true for k > 2.

Answer (score -1):

The time complexity of calculating the binomial coefficient C(n, k) can be expressed in different ways, depending on the algorithm used. The most common methods to calculate C(n, k) include:

1. Direct Calculation: The straightforward method is to use the binomial coefficient formula:

   C(n, k) = n! / (k! * (n - k)!),

Calculating factorials has a time complexity of O(n), so the time complexity for calculating C(n, k) using this formula is O(n) (or Θ(n)).

2. Dynamic Programming: Another common approach is to use dynamic programming to calculate C(n, k) more efficiently. This is typically done using a 2D array to store intermediate results and has a time complexity of O(n * k) (or Θ(n*k)).
3. Pascal's Triangle: If you have precomputed Pascal's triangle or a memoization table, you can look up the value of C(n, k) in constant time. Building Pascal's triangle requires O(n^2) time, but once it's constructed, accessing values is O(1).

### So, the time complexity of C(n, k) depends on the method you choose.

A short message to Clement C and IY3:

In the context of the binomial coefficient (n choose k), it is indeed correct to say that (n choose k) is Θ(n^k). The reason for this is that (n choose k) is a polynomial function of degree k in n. In Big O notation (Θ notation), we look for upper bounds or tight bounds on the growth of a function. In this case, the growth of (n choose k) is proportional to n^k, so we can represent it as Θ(n^k).

Your initial logic is valid, but you made it more complicated than it needed to be. (n choose k) is indeed Θ(n^k) because it's a polynomial function of n with degree k. The constants involved in k! and other terms do not change the overall polynomial nature of the function. But as I mentioned above, it can be of Θ(n) or Θ(n*k).

Comment: What part are you saying is wrong about the other answer? They said that that product tends to $1$, not $0$.

Comment: Thanks Varun, I edited my answer.

Comment: Just an important note: Dynamic programming is usually faster than direct computation for calculating binomial coefficients (C(n, k)) because it avoids the need to repeatedly compute factorials, which can be time-consuming for large n and k. Although dynamic programming has a theoretically higher time complexity (O(n * k)) compared to direct computation (O(n)), it's more efficient in practice, especially for larger n and k, due to the avoidance of expensive factorial calculations. So dynamic programming is a preferred method for calculating C(n,k) in most cases.

Comment: The question is about the value of the binomial coefficient, not the time complexity to compute it. Your answer is not answering the question.